# Object returned by Linq-to-objects operators - what is going on under the hood?

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

LINQ uses a Deferred Execution model which means that resulting sequence is not returned at the time the Linq operators are called, but instead these operators return an object which then yields elements of a sequence only when we enumerate this object.

```
var results = someCollection.Select(item => item.Foo).Where(foo => foo < 3);
```

When we enumerate results object, it will iterate through `someCollection` only once, and for each item requested during the iteration, code ( located inside `results` object ) performs the map operation and finally performs the filtering.

But I'm having trouble understanding what is going on under the hood:

a) Is `Where` method the one that actually creates `results` object?

b) If `Where` does create `results` object, then I'm assuming `Where` needs to also exctract some logic from `Select` operator (  such as `return Item.Foo` ) so that it can place that logic into `results` object?

c) If my assumptions are correct, how is `Where` able to extract the logic out of `Select`?

d) Anyways, `results` object contains the necessary logic **L** to evaluate each item in `someCollection`. I assume this logic **L** doesn't make any additional calls to `Select` and `Where` operators when evaluating each item in `someCollection`?

Thank you

**EDIT:**

1)

> Your assumption in d) is incorrect - results is just an
>   IEnumerable which is returned by the Where() extension
>   method. Only when you iterate over the enumeration (i.e. using foreach
>   or ToList()) will the sequence be created "for real". At that point -
>   you can even see this if you set a break point - all the Linq
>   extension methods are executed in turn - the Where() extension method
>   will ask the input IEnumerable for its first item, which will cause
>   the Select() operator in turn will get the first item from the
>   underlying collection and spit out a FooType item.

a) So `Where` and `Select` are first called in the assignment statement when assigning resulting object to `results` variable ( `var results=...` ). And then in turn `Where` / `Select` are also called ( from within the `results` object ) for each item when enumerating `someCollection`?

b) Assuming `results` instance is of type **C** – when is **C** class defined/created? Is it defined by `Where` method, or is class **C** defined by compiler and thus `Where` only returns an instance of `C`?

2)

> Only when you iterate over the enumeration (i.e. using foreach or
>   ToList()) will the sequence be created "for real". At that point - you
>   can even see this if you set a break point - all the Linq extension
>   methods are executed in turn - the Where() extension method will ask
>   the input IEnumerable for its first item, which will cause the
>   Select() operator in turn will get the first item from the underlying
>   collection and spit out a FooType item

a) You're saying that from within `results` object `Select` and `Where` are called for each item **I** in a collection. Assuming **I** doesn't implement `IEnumerable<>`,  how then can `Select` and `Where` be called on `I` if they can only operate on `IEnumerable<>` types?

Comment: For a great way to dive under the hood, see Jon Skeet's Edulinq series: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/09/03/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-1-introduction.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it like this, because this is what happens at compile time anyway:

```
var results = someCollection.Select(item => item.Foo).Where(foo => foo < 3);
```

is translated into

```
var results = Enumerable.Where(
                  Enumerable.Select(
                      someCollection, item => item.Foo
                  ),
                  foo => foo < 3
              );
```

So now it's clear that the `Where` operates on the result of `Select`. Then `Where` will pull from its source (in this case, the result of `Enumerable.Select`) and yield one at a time the items from the source that match the predicate (in this case `foo < 3`).

The implementation will look something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Where<T>(
    IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, bool> predicate
) {
    foreach(var item in source) {
        if(predicate(item)) {
            yield return item;
        }
    }
}

public static IEnumerable<U> Select<T, U>(
    IEnumerable<T> source,
    Func<T, U> project
) {

    foreach(var item in source) {
        yield project(item);
    }
}
```

So what happens is that when you want to pull an item from `results`, `Where` will pull from `Select` until it find an item that matches the predicate. It might have to pull a lot of items until it finds one to yield back to you. Meanwhile, every time that it pulls from `Select`, `Select` pulls another item from `someCollection` and yield backs the projection (`item.Foo`). When you try to pull another item from `Where`, `Where` will pull the next however many items it needs from `Select` until it finds one to yield back to you. If `Select` exhausts `someCollection` at any point, `Where` will know it has exhausted the supply of items as well and will stop yielding back to you.

Comment: Ok, it started making sense when you showed that my code is actually translated into "Enumerable.Where(Enumerable.Select(...". But just to be sure --> since Where operator uses iterator block to implement IEnumerable, compiler automatically generates appropriate enumerator class C, an instance of which Where method returns to results variable?

Comment: Roughly that's true. The exact implementation detail, I think, is that `Where<T>` returns `WhereEnumerableIterator<T>`. That's the class that actually implements the filtering, and is probably implemented using an iterator block that the compiler translates into an enumerator. When you call `Where<T>(source, predicate)`, the method just returns to you a `WhereEnumerableIterator<T>` that holds the information it needs to know what to do when you start iterating. This is how it gets away with deferred evaluation.

Answer (score 3):

The key is that all of these Linq extension methods are chained. Each works on the output of the previous extension method, for Linq to Objects (Linq to SQL makes some optimizations on the other hand) at least each extension method **does not have to know anything else besides the immediate enumeration that is its input**.

Each of these extension method takes an `IEnumerable` of a specific type as input, and yields its results again an `IEnumerable` (of a possibly different type when using `Select()`). Because of this restriction and chainability you can compose Linq extension methods in different ways, which makes Linq so flexible and powerful.

So for your example `Select()` operates on an `IEnumerable<YourCollectionType>` and yields results of `IEnumerable<FooType>`. `Where()` operates on an  `IEnumerable<FooType>` and filters this sequence and again yields `IEnumerable<FooType>`.

Your assumption in d) is incorrect - `results` is just an `IEnumerable<FooType>` which is returned by the `Where()` extension method. Only when you iterate over the enumeration (i.e. using `foreach` or `ToList()`) will the sequence be created "for real". At that point - you can even see this if you set a break point - all the Linq extension methods are executed in turn - the `Where()` extension method will ask the input `IEnumerable` for its first item, which will cause the `Select()` operator in turn will get the first item from the underlying collection and spit out a `FooType` item.

Comment: @user702769: the types themselves don't matter here - each extension method in your example has an output of `IEnumerable<SomeType>`. The IEnumerable interface has a method `GetEnumerator()` which returns an `IEnumerator` which allows enumerating the items in the IEnumerable and retrieving the individual items using `GetNext()` and `Current`